# Real location of OneDrive folder in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, reparse-points

I specified a custom location for the personal OneDrive folder while installing the OneDrive client in my Windows 10 Pro v1903. I placed this folder in the root of the drive D. After using this folder for some days I found that not all apps like backup software work with this folder correctly. It seems, the OneDrive folder I see in the Explorer is a virtual folder and all my files are not really stored on the drive D, which causes the problems I have.

The Explorer itself tells me that my OneDrive folder is on the desktop:

[image]

, but my desktop does not show this OneDrive folder.

I also can't find OneDrive in the system Indexing Options dialog - though the files in my OneDrive folder are indexed by the system.

The file manager Total Commander I'm using shows the OneDrive folder like a reparse point too:

[image]

So can anybody tell me how the OneDrive folder is implemented in Windows 10 and whether it is possible to find the real location of my files inside this folder? I am afraid my files could be stored on the system SSD drive, and I would want to avoid this and save my files really on the HDD drive D for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The **OneDrive** that appears under the **Desktop** is a namespace junction, similar to the user folders that appear under **This PC**, that 'points' to an actual file system location. The registry entry that places it on the **Desktop** is:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}
```

and, if the location of the **OneDrive** folder was changed from its default, you should see your `D:\OneDrive` path as the data for the value named `{A52BBA46-E9E1-435f-B3D9-28DAA648C0F6}` under:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

OneDrive does some unique things with attributes, one of which is setting the **L (link)** attribute on its actual file system folders, and that is probably confusing  **Total Commander**.
[image]

The best way to determine a folder's or file's location in the file system is to view its **Properties** dialog or add the **Folder Path** column to a **Details** view in **File Explorer**.
[image]

EDIT: The `dir /ad` command distinguishes between directories & reparse points:

```
C:\Users\keith>dir /ad
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is F057-590D

 Directory of C:\Users\keith

08/19/2019  04:12 PM    <DIR>          .
08/19/2019  04:12 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/26/2018  01:42 PM    <DIR>          .cache
07/21/2018  06:37 AM    <DIR>          .gimp-2.8
07/21/2018  06:37 AM    <DIR>          .thumbnails
07/19/2019  08:49 PM    <DIR>          AppData
07/19/2019  07:51 PM    <JUNCTION>     Application Data [C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming]
07/19/2019  09:31 PM    <DIR>          Contacts
07/19/2019  07:51 PM    <JUNCTION>     Cookies [C:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies]
08/16/2019  05:38 PM    <DIR>          Desktop
08/09/2019  04:12 PM    <DIR>          Documents
08/12/2019  05:59 PM    <DIR>          Downloads
08/14/2019  09:18 PM    <DIR>          Favorites
05/15/2019  11:20 AM    <DIR>          Google_files
08/17/2019  10:59 AM    <DIR>          IntelGraphicsProfiles
08/14/2019  09:18 PM    <DIR>          Links
07/19/2019  07:51 PM    <JUNCTION>     Local Settings [C:\Users\keith\AppData\Local]
07/21/2018  02:22 AM    <DIR>          MicrosoftEdgeBackups
08/14/2019  09:18 PM    <DIR>          Music
07/19/2019  07:51 PM    <JUNCTION>     My Documents [C:\Users\keith\Documents]
08/14/2019  09:18 PM    <DIR>          mycontacts
07/19/2019  07:51 PM    <JUNCTION>     NetHood [C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts]
08/17/2019  11:01 AM    <DIR>          OneDrive
08/21/2019  04:39 PM    <DIR>          Pictures
07/19/2019  07:51 PM    <JUNCTION>     PrintHood [C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts]
07/19/2019  07:51 PM    <JUNCTION>     Recent [C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent]
08/22/2019  01:33 PM    <DIR>          Sandbox
08/14/2019  09:18 PM    <DIR>          Saved Games
08/21/2019  06:18 PM    <DIR>          Screenshots
08/14/2019  09:18 PM    <DIR>          Searches
07/19/2019  07:51 PM    <JUNCTION>     SendTo [C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo]
07/20/2019  10:52 AM    <DIR>          Standalone Programs
07/19/2019  07:51 PM    <JUNCTION>     Start Menu [C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
07/19/2019  07:51 PM    <JUNCTION>     Templates [C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates]
04/30/2019  11:48 AM    <JUNCTION>     TESTJUN [\??\C:\users\keith\documents\recipes]
08/14/2019  09:18 PM    <DIR>          Videos
12/23/2018  09:18 PM    <DIR>          Work
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              37 Dir(s)  692,424,450,048 bytes free
```

Comment: I see the Link attribute for all folders in my OneDrive, even for those I set 'Free up space'. Do such items are really on my hard drives? The Folder Path column in the Explorer still shows D:\OneDrive for them...

Comment: **Free Up Space** tells OneDrive it can delete the file contents from your drive, but the directory structure and file info remain.

Comment: I created a directory symbolic link with `mklink /d`, but the **Folder Path** column in the Explorer does not show the real location of the folder. So either I am doing something wrong, or your solution does not allow me to know what I need.

Comment: Sure, **Folder Path** will show the path _of_ the link, not the path _to_ its target. I think what you're missing is this: OneDrive files & folders have the **L** attribute set even though they aren't Links.

Comment: Did you want to say that the **L** attribute is set even for the files that are located in the OneDrive folder and its subfolders on their places - exactly as we see them in the Explorer? If so, then it's really confusing.

Comment: I think I _did_ say that. :)

Comment: Hopeful clarification: I suggested adding the **Folder Path** column to help clarify the fact that the **OneDrive** in the **Navigation Pane/Desktop** was accessing the files/folders on  D:\ . I only mentioned the **L** atribute because it seemed to be confusing **Total Commander** (and therefore you as well) as to whether D:\OneDrive is a directory or a reparse point. Open Command Prompt (not PowerShell) and execute `dir /ad` for an accurate distinction between directories & reparse points.